# Powershell AES 256 - How to encode key and iv for decryption?

Tags: powershell, cryptography, aes

I stumbled upon the code below to generate an AES-256 secret and I'm trying to get the right encoding for the key/IV to decrypt the cipher using any AES-256 online decoder.

Here are the results i'm getting so far, problem is i need the key in 32 length and IV in 16, i first tried converting the b64 string to utf-8 but it produces unknown characters.

Then i took the decimal value and converted it, but likewise it produces unknown characters.

```
2023-08-31T12:22:44.583 [Information] INFORMATION: AES-Key is OSyqOu9mCEFOORD0ziDRs98+qro/Fztdn9Oev9T9Ewc= : 57 44 170 58 239 102 8 65 78 57 16 244 206 32 209 179 223 62 170 186 63 23 59 93 159 211 158 191 212 253 19 7 : 9,ª:ïfV9UG>,Î Ñ³ß>ªº?ëc;Ó¿ÔýÅ

2023-08-31T12:22:44.649 [Information] INFORMATION: IV : ijsDZzP9n7u2q8EEHLBo9g== : 138 59 3 103 51 253 159 187 182 171 193 4 28 176 104 246 : ;#};»¶«Á*QLhö

2023-08-31T12:22:44.649 [Information] INFORMATION: EncryptedString is ijsDZzP9n7u2q8EEHLBo9ghBKy4ES0yosW3Elwu/R9o=
```

**Encrypt.ps1** -- src : https://medium.com/asecuritysite-when-bob-met-alice/aes-encryption-with-powershell-e9e5ee733d20

```
function Create-AesKey() {
    $aesManaged = Create-AesManagedObject
    $aesManaged.GenerateKey()
    [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($aesManaged.Key)
}

function Encrypt-String($key, $unencryptedString) {
    $bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($unencryptedString)
    $aesManaged = Create-AesManagedObject $key
    $encryptor = $aesManaged.CreateEncryptor()
    $encryptedData = $encryptor.TransformFinalBlock($bytes, 0, $bytes.Length);
    [byte[]] $fullData = $aesManaged.IV + $encryptedData
    $iv = [Convert]::ToBase64String($aesManaged.IV)
    Write-Host "IV = $iv : $($aesManaged.IV)"
    $aesManaged.Dispose()
    [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($fullData)
}

$key = Create-AesKey
$okey = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($key)
Write-Host "AES-Key is $key : $okey"
$unencryptedString = "blahblahblah"
$encryptedString = Encrypt-String $key $unencryptedString
Write-Host "EncryptedString is $encryptedString"
```

Comment: Usually key and IV are random byte sequences. These cannot be UTF-8 decoded without corrupting the data. If you want to convert the data into a string, you have to choose a binary-to-text encoding, like Base64 or Hex. Reasonable online tools (e.g. Cyberchef) allow you to select an encoding for key, IV and ciphertext. The PS script outputs IV and key already Base64 encoded.

Comment: However, `Encrypt-String` does not return the (Base64 encoded) ciphertext, but the Base64 encoded concatenation of IV and ciphertext. Since online tools usually do not separate implicitly, this must be done by you. Alternatively, the ciphertext can be output in `Encrypt-String` Base64 encoded like the IV.

Comment: Example for a decryption with CyberChef (key, IV and ciphertext were generated with the PS script): https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=From_Base64('A-Za-z0-9%2B/%3D',true,false)AES_Decrypt(%7B'option':'Base64','string':'GvbpErmRidP2N2/B/0rb4kQ8EN9QTrc7FvcrrW40KZQ%3D'%7D,%7B'option':'Base64','string':'3gUzz9OI0pX9Z4tHnqSEmA%3D%3D'%7D,'CBC','Raw','Raw',%7B'option':'Hex','string':''%7D,%7B'option':'Hex','string':''%7D)&input=UFhsVmlyUi91TXBPZU9odHA0blBLZz09

Comment: Thank you for your clarification, very clear, so i tried simplifying the decryption function used for my ps1 code before and it looks like this : ((Create-AesManagedObject $key $IV).CreateDecryptor()).TransformFinalBlock($bytes, 16, $bytes.Length - 16), can i go ahead and assume that i can use the (b64 cipher + iv) obtained as result, remove first 16 bytes and decipher the remaining portion ? The reason i ask is because i need to decrypt this on a different client (JS)

Comment: `Encrypt-String` returns the Base64 encoding of the concatenation of IV and ciphertext: `Base64(IV+ciphertext)`. This must first be Base64 decoded. From this result the first 16 bytes are the IV and the rest is the actual ciphertext. If IV and ciphertext are to be passed as string, both have to be encoded again *separately* with e.g. Base64.